# How do I do an internal curve on a column?

Tags: modeling, bevel, proportional-editing

The context here is that I am modelling an gothic column, at some points it curves inwards.
[image: column]

Comment: Have you considered more vertices in that area and the bevel tool?  Proportional Edit is also available.   I suggest searching for introductory videos at the famous video website or here at BSE.  Loop Cut tool is available to create more vertex density.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I tried a bezel, but they only seem to go out of the column, not inwards.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=znZGx3CIqX4
just a quick random choice .. you can find one that suits your tastes

Comment: The word profile in the context of Bevel will help you.